# Need help with PHP "include" - How to save the path to my website in variable?

Tags: php, include, require, include-path

I use the following scheme to include PHP files:

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "Path/To/My/Website/Path/To/My/File.php");
```

I would like to save

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'Path/To/My/Website'
```

in some variable, say `$my_website`, and write:

```
require("$my_website/Path/To/My/File.php");
```

This way, if I decide to change the path to my website, I will need to modify it only in one place in my code.

Some PHP files may be included several times and from different directory levels. For example:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
                         Path
                             To
                               My
                                 Website
                                        Dir1
                                            a.php
                                        Dir2
                                            b.php that includes a.php
                                        Dir3
                                            Dir4
                                                c.php that includes a.php
```

However, I can't think how to do this.

Please suggest.

Comment: I Maybe not understanding what you exactly want, but couldn't you just add the path to your include paths and go full relative? Or just define the BasePath in your bootstrap ... or whats stopping you from just writing `require($my_website . "/Path/To/My/File.php");` ? (but of course, to define something would be better then to throw this variable around)

Comment: Only a configuration with single entry point could let you do it using PHP. Otherwise some web-server config changes are required. Obvious things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [include path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) - will make your life simpler (you can control it even from .htaccess).

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways of doing this:

1. Create a common file, included in every other file, that set your variable `$my_website`
2. Add your website path to your include_path so you don't have to use you website path at all to include your files (`require "Path/To/My/File.php";`)

Comment: In #1: how would you include that common file (what path would you use) ? Suppose in my example above that `a.php` is the common file.

Comment: I'll put it in my website root and include it using relative path: this will work as long as you don't change your directory structure. So for your example b.php -> require '../Dir1/a.php' and c.php -> require '../../Dir1/a.php'. But as other answers noted it's best to use include_path

Answer (score 0):

I set constants for BASE_PATH and BASE_URI in my `config.php` file, which is in the same folder as the scripts and gets included in each script (`require('config.php')`):

```
define('BASE_PATH', '/filesystem/path/to/application');
define('BASE_URI', '/uri/home');
```

Then you can use:

```
require(BASE_PATH . '/file.php');
```

One further hint - if you have seperate development and live sites, you can put these definitions in a switch:

```
$mode = 'dev';
switch($mode){
    case 'dev':
        define('BASE_PATH', '/filesystem/path/to/application');
        define('BASE_URI', '/uri/home');
    break;
    case 'live':
        define('BASE_PATH', '/different/path/to/application');
        define('BASE_URI', '/');
    break;
}
```

Comment: The question is what path do you use to include `config.php` ?

Comment: Then maybe you should word it more clearly rather than downvoting. Either way, I put time and effort into providing an answer - how about saying "thanks, but..."?

Comment: Sorry, man, but I didn't downvote you... I appreciate your effort to help.