# Where PHP "set_include_path" is effective?

Tags: php, include, include-path, set-include-path

I would like to add `my_path` to `include_path` and `include` files relatively to `my_path`.

Is that enough to set the `include_path` using `set_include_path` in the main PHP file of my website, or I must do this in every PHP file ?

Comment: why not to ask it as a comment to the answers to your previous question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need help with PHP "include" - How to save the path to my website in variable ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976970/need-help-with-php-include-how-to-save-the-path-to-my-website-in-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to repeat it for each included file. An alternative approach would be using .htaccess files:

```
php_value include_path new_path:/old/paths/here
```